# How to return javascript variables in json response and display their values on document

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I am returning the string in json response :

**item.php**

```
    $ItemList =array (itemcode=>EATERY, itemname=>'Popcorn') ;


    $ItemDisplay =

 "  
                '<div>' +  document.write(this.itemname) +  ' - ' + 
                          document.write(this.itemcode) +'</div>' 
            "; 


        echo "{'itemlist':$ItemList, itemdisplay:$ItemDisplay}";
```

Now in the html file i want that the output is displayed. i.e. the value of the variables embedded in the json are displayed :

**itemlist.html**

```
var itemlist = '';
$.each(response.itemlist, function (i){


    itemdisplay += data.items;



});



$('#itemlist').html(itemdisplay );
```

**Output required :**

```
<div>Popcorn - EATERY</div>
<div>Burger - EATERY</div>
<div>Napkin - ACCESSORY</div>
```

**Update :**

itemlist is an array (itemcode=>EATERY, itemname=>'Popcorn')

Comment: `item.php` can return html code and you will just use `html()`

Comment: I see what the result is you want, but what is the result you get?

Comment: @jrswgtr : dear sir,  i have embedded javascript variables (itemcode & itemname) in a php string. now i want that the value of those variables should be displayed in the html file

Comment: @sqlchild where did you declare `itemname` and `itemcode`?

Comment: You cannot use document.write after page load. Use JSON

Comment: You need to return this kind of JSON: ` { "EATERY": ["Popcorn","Burger"], "ACCESSORY": ["Napkin"]}`

Answer (score 1):

**Php** - create the required markup and pass it to client:

```
$ItemList = '<div>Item1 - Name 1</div><div>Item2 - Name 2</div><div>Item3 - Name 3</div>';
echo json_encode(['items' => $ItemList]);
```

**Js** - just insert provided html to the element of your choice:

```
$('#itemlist').html(response.items);
```

Comment: : dear sir, i have embedded javascript variables (itemcode & itemname) in a php string. now i want that the value of those variables should be displayed in the html file

Comment: And why do you need to embed js variables?

Comment: dear sir i have updated my question please i would request you to please check it out once again

Comment: i don't want to depend on the html file... i will just change the php and it will display accordingly

Comment: __Nothing__ in your question explains why do you use some js variables in html markup.

Comment: dear sir, i don't want to depend on the html file for editing as it is with another developer... i will just edit the php and it will display accordingly

Comment: So I provided you a solution when you make all data that you need on php side.

Comment: Your approach is quite bad, Make an array in php and then echo json encoded that array, it will create a json object useful in your javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that this is your **itemlist.html** code:

```
var itemdisplay = '';

$.each(response.itemlist, function (key, value){
    itemdisplay += value;
});

$('#itemlist').html(itemdisplay);
```

so your **item.php** should be something like this:

```
$itemList = [
    ['itemcode' => 'EATERY', 'itemname' => 'Popcorn'],
    ['itemcode' => 'EATERY', 'itemname' => 'Burger'],
    ['itemcode' => 'ACCESSORY', 'itemname' => 'Napkin']
];

$json = [];

foreach($itemList as $item){
    $json[] = '<div>' . $item['itemname'] . ' - ' .  $item['itemcode'] . '</div>';
}

json_encode(['itemlist' => $json], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```